# Validation Rule: If Multi-Select picklist selects 'Other'

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I'm working on creating a validation rule where I have:

- Multi-Select-Picklist (`multi_select_picklist__c`)
- Text field (`other_explanation__c`)

The rule is: If the user selects `Other` from multi-select pick list then `other_explanation__c` is required to enter.

I have attempted to do something like this:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Career Advisor - Inbound'), 
AND(ISPICKVAL(multi_select_picklist__c != 'Other')), ISBLANK(other_explanation__c)
OR( 
    $Profile.Name == "Administrator", 
    $Profile.Name =="Super User" 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multi-select picklists with `ISPICKVAL`. Instead, you need to use `INCLUDES`. The [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0) describes its use as follows:

> `INCLUDES(`***`multiselect_picklist_field`***`,`***`text_literal`***`)` and replace `multiselect_picklist_field` with the merge field name for the multi-select picklist; and replace `text_literal` with the multi-select picklist value you want to match in quotes.

So your formula should look something like this:

```
AND(
 $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator',
 ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Career Advisor - Inbound'),
 ISBLANK(other_explanation__c),
 INCLUDES(multi_select_picklist__c, 'Other')
)
```

Comment: one question can you use $Label in the Validation rule? instead of hard-coding the value, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_label.htm

Comment: Not in validation rules that I know of.

Comment: Yes the `$Label` global variable is accessible within `Validation Rules`.

Comment: @Adrian: I have tried it for the multi-select got this error `Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'INCLUDES()'. Expected Text Literal, received Text
`

Comment: `INCLUDES(multi_select_picklist__c, $Label.Other)`

Comment: It has to be text literal.. What if you tried INCLUDES(multi_Select_Picklist__c, TEXT($Label.Other))